# execute python instruction when console is closed

Tags: python, windows, console

I want to do a Python script that would do some instructions when a PC is started and the user is not recognized.

When the PC starts, a batch files (I'm on Windows 7) launches the Python script, which asks a password. If the user closes the Python console where the password is asked, I want Python to execute one last function before closing completely the window.

Something on the model bellow, but it doesn't work.

```
try:
    # ask for the password
except:
    # do the thing I want (not executed when the console is closed unfortunatelly)
```

Thanks in advance

SLP

Comment: You don't need a batch script. The console is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe, which has nothing to do with CMD, other than the fact that cmd.exe uses a console, just like python.exe does. Just run the Python script directly.

Comment: When the console is closed, all attached processes are sent a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. This gets mapped to `SIGBREAK` in Python, but it can't be handled due to the way Python's signal handler is designed (i.e. set a flag and return immediately). For the close event, the session server (csrss.exe) gives a client process 5 seconds to return. After the client either returns or times out, it is forcefully terminated, unless it already exited on its own. To handle this event, you'll need to use ctypes to set your own console control handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to register a ctypes callback.

Comment: @eryksun Actually I want the script to start automatically at the boot so I don't think I can do it without the batch file

Comment: @eryksun I don't see why the ctypes are necessary here. anyway I think I have my answer : if I want to do something when a script's console is closed manually, it can't be with the same script. right ?

Comment: No. As I said, if you use ctypes to call the native WINAPI function `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, passing it a ctypes callback function with the documented handler prototype, then you can handle `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. The system gives a console client 5 seconds to do whatever it needs to do and exit on its own. Then it forcefully terminates the process.

Answer (score 0):

Make a batch script with the python ejecution and especify a exit code if the password is input, then check the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable, if the variable correspond with the exit code means that the password was entered.